# Creating a Rest API without database and authentication

Tags: api, rest

I am having a bit of a trouble understanding the whole idea of Rest APIs.

Say I want to create a web service where users send a string to the service using HTTP Get command, the the service will reverse the string (`mystring -> gnirtsym`), and returns it. That's it. I am watching and reading a lot of tutorials and all of them talk about how I need to assign an ID, and authentication and query into the database and stuff. But for the task I just mentioned, I don't need any of these. No need for authentication and/or different IDs and endpoints and database.

Does that make any sense? Or is a REST API a REST API only if it has DB and authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a simple REST API without any DB or user identification, authentication etc.

It's just not a very common use case, but no one is saying you couldn't do that :-)